# How do I return a firebase user to access certain elements

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to write a function in one file to get the current signed in user in other files.

Right now, I just have it return the user, However,  when calling that function, I get Instance of Firebase User in console. When trying `getSignedInUser().uid`, it says Class `Future<dynamic>` has no instance getter `uid`. If within my function, I print out `mCurrentUser.uid` (to the console), I do get the proper printout. I don't want it in the console. If in another file, I want access, for instance, the current user's email, I would like to call that function like `getSignedInUser().email` (when the function returns that user)

**In authentication.dart:**

```
getSignedInUser() async {
  mCurrentUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
  if(mCurrentUser == null || mCurrentUser.isAnonymous){
    print("no user signed in");
  }
  else{
    return mCurrentUser;
    //changing above line to print(mCurrentUser.uid) works, but that's useless 
    //for the purpose of this function
  }
}
```

in `homescreen.dart` after logging in, I have a button that checks the current user:

```
Widget checkUserButton() {
    return RaisedButton(
      color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, 1.0),
      child: Text("who's signed in?", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
      onPressed: () {
        print(getSignedInUser().uid);
        //applying change to comments in getSignedInUser() function above 
        //changes this to just call getSignedInUser()
      },
    );
  }
```

I would expect this take the returned user from `getSignedInUser()` function and allow me to use those built in functions from the Firebase Auth class. However, those don't autofill like expected, just throwing runtime error as stated above. I only printed it to the console to see my output as a test. Once I know I'm accessing fields such as the user id, then I can use that info to do what I need to from any other screens (as long as I import authentication.dart). Thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 1):

You forgot that your `getSignedInUser` function is an async function so it returns a Future object in your case a `Future<FirebaseUser>` instance.  You're trying read `uid` property from a Future object instance that is why you got the error message:
**'Future' has no instance getter 'uid'**.

To solve this you just need to `await` your function to read the right results.

```
Widget checkUserButton() {
    return RaisedButton(
      color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, 1.0),
      child: Text("who's signed in?", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
      onPressed: () async { // make on pressed async
        var fbUser = await = getSignedInUser(); // wait the future object complete
        print(fbUser.uid); // gotcha!
        //applying change to comments in getSignedInUser() function above 
        //changes this to just call getSignedInUser()
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: ah ha! Thank you very much. That was the missing piece